# What shopping carts integrate well with MYOB?

Tags: seo, web-development, ecommerce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Ecommerce Script Should I Use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30150/which-ecommerce-script-should-i-use)

I'm trying to select an eCommerce solution that will integrate with the accounting program, [AccountEdge](http://www.accountedge.com/) (from [MYOB](http://acclivitysoftware.com/about/)). I also need it to be SEO-friendly and be able to print shipping labels, directly. I will also consider any stable add-ons to any given shopping cart.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but KashFlow (a competitor to MYOB) has healthy compatibility with many eCommerce solutions.

Answer (score 1):

[EnStore WebStore](http://www.accountedge.com/webstore/) appears to be the officially sanctioned shopping cart.